# PyCharm не понимает методы OpenCV

Tags: opencv, pycharm

Прежде чем задать этот вопрос я просмотрел другие похожие темы, но не нашел решения.
При вводе методов, PyCharm не дает подсказки и выделяет сами методы. При наведении мышкой на методы, пишет

> 'Cannot find reference 'imread' in '**init**.py'

> Cannot find reference 'COLOR_BGR2R' in '**init**.py'

> Cannot find reference 'cvtColor' in '**init**.py'

При попытке запуска кода, выдает такую ошибку:

> module 'cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2R'

Попробовал установить более старые версии OpenCV,другие версии интерпретатора и PyCharm, но тщетно.
Вот тестовый код, больше ничего нету:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("4.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cnf = r"--oem 1 --psm 4"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=cnf)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В правом нижнем углу PyCharm выбираем **`Interpreter Settings`**
2. В списке виртуальных окружений выбираем своё
3. Нажимаем **`Show path for the selected interpreter`**
4. Указываем путь **`<Your vevn>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2`**
5. Не забываем **`Apply`**

Вот так вкратце:

```
Interpreter Settings... 
  -> Show All... 
    -> Show path for the selected interpreter 
      -> [Add] -> <Your vevn>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2 
        -> [OK] 
          -> [Apply]
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла установка библиотек именно в сам python и по совету одного паренька, перекинул файл cv2.pyd из папки cv2 в папку site-package и проблема была частично решена, код запускается, но выделение методов и отсутствие подсказок осталось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ошибка, мне помогло просто в терминале в PyCharme написать pip install opencv-python.
При этом я уже ставил до этого opencv, но заработал именно так