# Pycharm не видит установленную библиотеку Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, pycharm, библиотеки

Установил в Pycharm для заказа библиотеку Aiogram, при запуске ТГ бот работает, ошибок никаких нет, только в самом коде подсказок по методам библиотеки нет совсем. В Settings->Python Interpreter Aiogram установлен, и даже если через pip устанавливать, то все работает, только не работает проверка синтаксиса и т.д. Пробовал переустановить Pycharm, но не помогло.
[image: Скрин Pycharm]

[image: Скрин Interpreter]

Comment: Зайдите в Python Packages внизу окнам(там где терминал и консоль) и посмотрите установлен ли он там

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да, все установлено

Comment: А если навести на выделенный красным текст?

Comment: @oleksandrigo Unresolved reference 'aiogram'. Но при этом бот работает

Comment: Нажмите install package aiogram

Comment: @oleksandrigo Нажал, модуль установился, пришло уведомление, на секунду подчеркивание пропало, но потом вновь появилось

Comment: Добавьте скрин настроек интерпетатора

Comment: @oleksandrigo Сейчас пишет "Invalid Python SDK". Скрин сейчас приложу

Comment: @oleksandrigo Причем ошибка только при установке модуля Aiogram, с requests такого не заметил

Comment: Какую версию айограма вы пытаетесь установить?

Comment: @oleksandrigo Ту, которую предлагает Pycharm 2.22.1

Comment: @oleksandrigo Причем дело не в том, что бот не работает, а в том, что Pycharm не дает подсказки по синтаксису

Comment: К слову у вас на скрине нет айограма

Comment: @oleksandrigo Установил Aiogram в Python Interpreter, но все равно ничего не изменилось

Comment: @oleksandrigo при перезапуске Pycharm на минуту все работает нормально, но потом импорты Aiogram подчеркиваются и пропадают подсказки по работе с ними

Comment: @auem, какие модули для Aiogram установил ?

Comment: Аналогичная проблема описывалась для opencv. Решение есть по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1419331/pycharm-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы в переустановке Pycharm и Python. После переустановки попробовал установить необходимые модули в Python на самом ПК, запустил через CMD. После этого уже установил Pycharm и сделал там то же самое: установил модули необходимые для проекта через Ctrl+Alt+S -> Python Interpreter.